# Single word for making a situation doubly worse

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm thinking of a situation, wherein instead of helping someone's cause the helper rather doubly complicates the problem by giving an uneasy solution to it. For example, I'm assuming a person who doesn't know the meaning of the word sorry, he's tried to be helped with the synonym apologetic, of which he has no clue either, now his problem is twofold and his cause hasn't been helped but rather complicated.

Answer (score 4):

Try **compound**. According to NOAD, it means:

> make (something bad) worse; intensify the negative aspects of : *I compounded the problem by trying to make wrong things right*.

That fits your context:

> What does the word *sorry* mean?
>   It means "apologetic".
>   Egads! I don't know what *apologetic* means; you've only **compounded** my problem.

Comment: I like that term. It never crossed my mind that what I was looking for could be as simple as that.

Answer (score 4):

To [exacerbate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/exacerbate):

> - Make (a problem, bad situation, or negative feeling) worse.

- The police intervention to calm the crowd unluckily exacerbated the situation and new episodes of violence took place.

Comment: @Andy Semyonov *Obfuscate* might be the term you were looking for, but this is the answer to the question as worded.

Answer (score 2):

> **ag·gra·vate**
>
> *verb*
>
> 1. make (a problem, injury, or offense) worse or more serious. "military action would only aggravate the situation"
> 2. informal annoy or exasperate (someone), especially persistently. "the gesture aggravated me even more"

From OED http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/aggravate

He was not a native English speaker, so when he found *apologetic* as the definition for *sorry* in the dictionary this only aggravated his situation, which in turn aggravated him.

Comment: Obfuscate was the term I was looking for. Thanks for your answer by the way.